# Numpy: how to copy a matrix to a column of n-D array?

Tags: python, numpy

I read an image and convert it to a grayscale one:

```
gs=cv2.imread('bgr.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

From `gs`, I want to create an empty picture which has a third dimension:

```
empty_image=numpy.zeros((gs.shape[0],gs.shape[1],3),dtype=numpy.uint8)
```

I want to copy the `L` values of the `gs` elements inside the first column of the third dimension I added in `empty_image`. How can I do that ?

Comment: What's the dtype of `gs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to copy your greyscale image into the first channel of your 3-channel image. You can do that as follows:

```
empty_image[:, :, 0] = gs
```

`empty_image[:, :, 0]` uses an index of zero in the third dimension (to select the first element), and selects all elements from the other dimensions.